# Display count of Viewbag list items

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

Hi is there a way to display a viewbag list  and show count

Like:

> United Arab Emirates(8)
>   Angola(4)
>   Argentina(7)
>   Austria(0)
>   Belgium(11)

Currently i have a Checkboxlist(costume helper) in view

```
@Html.CheckBoxList("checkedLocation", (ViewBag.country_list as MultiSelectList))
```

Only countries are displayed. Wud be great if the same list has counts
Basically i have a company table with country fields. Just wanna show that in Brazil, ten companies are available like **Brazil(10)**

This how the `viwbag` is populated

```
List<country> listInfo2 = db.countries.Where(row => row.covered == 1).ToList();
List<string> checkedValues = new List<string>();
MultiSelectList checkedValuesList = new MultiSelectList(listInfo2, "country_name", "country_name", checkedValues);
ViewBag.country_list = checkedValuesList
```

Comment: can you show how you are populating that Viewbag?

Comment: Just edited the controller code in

Comment: Quick question, what is the point of `checkedValues` if it is just an empty list of strings?  It doesn't have any `selected values`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally got it right
Controller:

```
//COUNTRIES TO CHECKBOX LIST
        List<DeviceGroupViewModel> listInfo2 = db.companies.GroupBy(fu => fu.COM_COUNTRY).Select(g => new DeviceGroupViewModel { Type = g.Key, Count = g.Count() }).ToList();
        MultiSelectList checkedValuesList = new MultiSelectList(listInfo2, "Type", "Count");
        ViewBag.country_list = checkedValuesList;
```

View:

```
 @Html.CheckBoxList2("checkedLocation", (ViewBag.country_list as MultiSelectList))
```

Checkboxlist Helper:

```
 public static MvcHtmlString CheckBoxList2(this HtmlHelper htmlHelper, string name, MultiSelectList listInfos)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(name))
        {
            throw new ArgumentException("This parameter cannot be null or empty!", "name");

        }
        if (listInfos == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentException("This parameter cannot be null!", "listInfos");
        }


        //if (listInfos.Count<SelectListItem>() < 1)
        //{
        //    throw new ArgumentException("The count must be greater than 0!", "listInfos");
        //}

        List<string> selectedValues = (List<string>)listInfos.SelectedValues;
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();



        foreach (SelectListItem info in listInfos)
        {

            sb.Append("<li class='Navlist'>");
            TagBuilder builder = new TagBuilder("input");

            if (info.Selected) builder.MergeAttribute("checked", "checked");

           //builder.MergeAttributes<string, object>(htmlAttributes);

            builder.MergeAttribute("type", "checkbox");

            builder.MergeAttribute("value", info.Value);

            builder.MergeAttribute("name", name);

            builder.MergeAttribute("id", info.Value);

            builder.MergeAttribute("class", "filter-classif");



            builder.InnerHtml = "<label>" + info.Value + "(" + info.Text + ")</label>";



            sb.Append(builder.ToString(TagRenderMode.Normal));
            sb.Append("</li>");



        }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can return a new dynamic list of objects. Here is the example:

```
public class country
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Covered { get; set; }
}
List<country> contries = new List<country>() { 
    new country(){ Name = "Siraj", Covered = "1"},
    new country(){ Name = "Kumail", Covered = "1"},
    new country(){ Name = "Ali", Covered = "1"},
    new country(){ Name = "Haider", Covered = "1"}
};
 var query = (from x in contries
              group x.Id by x.Name into g
              select new { CustomName = string.Format("{0} ({1})", g.Key, g.Count()) }).ToList();
```

Comment: Thanx Siraj for ur input. Above counts contries covered right? Looking for something that queries the company table. i.e Query how many times Brazil appears in the com_country field in all the rows.

Comment: Then you need a group by clause.I have updated the code accordingly.

Comment: i cant get that "var query" into  List<>. Idea is to query Company table and Count occurrences of Countries..